# CORENFC project not run from xcode to iphone 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nfc

I have an application built on Xcode. I am trying to add it to my phone for testing but continue to get the message "Iphone has denied the Launch Request".

The app is a tutorial downloaded from Github for CORENFC.

I have restarted my XCODE and Iphone many times with no change.

I also generating IPA and then tried to install, still I can't.

Please Give me any solution.

Comment: Which Xcode version it is?

Comment: Currenty xcode 10 i'm using, and in my device has ios12

Comment: when you are generating IPA what error you are getting on iPhone?

Comment: IPA is generating successfully. but When I'm installed in my device, it does the same thing.  Opens and then closes

Comment: This may help : https://www.google.co.in/search?client=opera&q=Iphone+has+denied+the+Launch+Request&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: I have checked this all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180498/discussion-between-monika-patel-and-dharmesh-kheni).

Comment: have you tried by creating a new provisioning profile?

Comment: Check your certificate. and restart the system

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that you have accepted your app in the developer profiles on your phone? If you want to check go settings > General > Device Managment and it should have your app under the developer app section.

This should be the reason the iPhone is denying the request to launch your app.

Hope I have helped, Toby